# What model or study to do when two metrics are affecting each other

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have two metrics, Call Volumes and Call Abandons. On a day with high call volumes, there comes high call abandons. While high call abandons will become a part of the call volumes later when customers call back, so the impacts between the two becoming a loop. We don't have a record who are the ones abandoned the calls and called back, so I am not sure how I can measure the true impact from abandoned calls and therefore isolate out the true demand of the calls (excluding the call backs). Is there any stats model/approach that can be used to evaluate cases similar to this?

cheers